# How to back sweeten an apple wine

Tags: cider

I'm going to brew an apple wine and would like this batch to be sweet. What is the best method to back sweeten an apple wine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do ciders and Apple wines a lot.

Not being a fan of chemical inhibitors, I crash and fine out the cider to brilliant clairity before kegging to limit suspended yeast.
I usually have about 4.5 gallons of cider to rack and add 1/2 gallon of store bought preservative free juice (usually the same juice that was fermented) to top off the keg. Then keep it refrigerated.  This backsweetens to my taste and is the simplest imo if you keg.

Answer (score 1):

Impede the yeast activity with either sorbate or metabisulfite.  Then add the sweetener of choice in the bottling phase to taste.  Bottle from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add some Honey that has non fermentable sugars, this will make you cinder more alcoholic and more sweet.
Instead of trying to kill you yeast with chemical products you must try to add non fermentable sugars (dextrine).
Here read this link: http://www.cider.org.uk/part4.htm

I never make cinder, but for get more body and sweetnes in beer i mash at higher temp to get Alpha-Amylase generate more non fermentable sugars.

Answer (score 0):

I put my cider in the fridge for 3 days than filter it into a keg, then add apple cider, and a roll of frozen concentrate from the grocery store.